# array value get as column in PHP

Tags: php

i want to get the names from an array, so i use **implode(" ",$names)**.

But the problem is i want them in a different way.

```
 $names[]=array('number1', 'number2','number3'); 

        $all = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {

            $data = array();
            $data['names'] = implode(" ",$names);
            $all[] = $data;
        }
```

Now the names are showing the output like ---

```
number number2 number3
```

But I want the names from the array like ---

```
number1
number2
number3
```

If I write

```
$data['names'] = implode("<BR>",$names);
```

returns me

```
number<BR>number2<BR>number3
```

I have also tried like ---

```
$data['names'] = implode("</br>",$names);
```

which return

```
number</br>number2</br>number3
```

How can I fix this problem !

Comment: Leave aside the fact that you're re-writing `data` to an empty array with each iteration you ended up with exactly the same array you had before. Your question doesn't exactly make sense. It's more about formatting that anything relating to logic.

Comment: [Check This](https://eval.in/425263)

Comment: I'll simply prefer `implode("<br>",$name[0])` instead of `foreach` loop and if you have single dimensional array then why are you making multidimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$names[]=array('number1', 'number2','number3'); 

$all = array();
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $all[] = implode(PHP_EOL, $name);
}
```

If you have to stamp the results on a web page replace `PHP_EOL` with `<br>` as below:

```
$all[] = implode("<br>", $name);
```

**UPDATE FOR PHP VERSION < 5.0.2**

Replace `PHP_EOL` with `chr(13)` as below:

```
$all[] = implode(chr(13), $name);
```

Comment: it returns this error ----Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed for this line $all[] = implode("<br>", $name);

Comment: Maybe you have a php version older than 5.0.2 so you can't use `PHP_EOL`. You have to replace it with `chr(13)` as you can see in my edited answer.